# How get the mod inverse

Tags: java, math, numbers, modulo

The expression is: `n mod m = x`

I want to know the value of `n` given `m` and `x`
Is possible to get this value ? Is there is a java function to get that number?

Comment: No, it's not possible, because there are many such `n` for any given `m` and `x`.

Comment: One value is `n = m + x` (although you probably have to handle negative values a bit specially).

Comment: n = m*k + x for some integer k

Comment: *the* value or *a* value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to get this value. There are in fact multiple possibilities for a given `m` and `x`. For example, take `n mod 3 = 1`. We know that `m` is 3 and `x` is 1, but just knowing that, we don't know whether `n` is 4 or 7 or 10 or 13 or any other number that is one more than a multiple of three.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done - look at a few examples

```
10 mod 9 = 1

19 mod 9 = 1
```

n could be 10, 19, 28 etc...
or

```
9 mod 8 = 1

17 mod 8 = 1
```

n could be 9, 17, 25 etc...